# How to list all the domains in India under one website based on categories

Tags: c#-4.0

I need to list all the website links (domains) in India under one website based on categories.

Comment: What specifically do you need help with? This is way too broad.

Comment: I suspect you are catastrophically underestimating the difficulty of what you want to do.

Comment: my client is running digital marketing he need all the website links in India to be listed in a web page, based on categories like (educational institutions, IT Companies, etc),  is this possible

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: So basically you're re-creating Yahoo from the 90s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just cannot list 100% of Indian websites. If I understand what you want, you want something like a [Web crawler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler) for Indian domains. Another "google". But even big spiders like Google's, Yahoo's, Bing's spiders can't build a database of all the websites. They do this with algorithms (with partly published algorithms), but I think you need even more, because you need a 100% accurate database, so you would need to have to ask them from all domain registrars, but you obviously can't do that.

Even if it was possible I definitely would not do this for a client, but created a company for that. But I would say that's practically impossible. 
What you can do is that you can search for a few thousands of sites and categorize them manually or build a small "spider".